# How to acces my local server without typing my ip?

Tags: raspbian, web-server

I would like to access to my Pi server (wich is not reachable on internet) in an other way than typing it's ip (192.168.1.3), something like http://myserver or even http://myserver.net rather than my ip

Comment: This should work out-of-the-box with raspbian and the hostname that is configured in `/etc/hostname`

Comment: @Ghanima Nope only via the raspi itselfand i want to acces via my laptop on the network

Comment: Then likely your laptop and/or other local network devices (wan-router / switch combo) is to blame, not the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a simple type A DNS record. You can acheive this by two different ways. The first, and the simplest, is to assign the hostname *myserver* to the *hosts* file on all the computers you want to connect to the server using that particular dns. The seccond is just buying (or getting for free) a domain and assigning that hostname to the ip, this will work but it's not ideal.

Comment: The first part seems a bit difficult because not every pc is on linux, and if i connect from another pc via vpn, i'll have to do it again and again. The second one does not make it accessible from all over the web ? And i have my own domain name .

Comment: On Windows the hosts file is at `%systemdrive%\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and works in about the same way as Linux and macOS. The hosts file approach is not scalable but thats a reason why DNS exists.

Comment: Yes, exactly like tobyd said. It works the same way on both linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

On a unmodified Raspbian installation you can reach your Raspberry Pi machine with url http://raspberrypi.local if you install a web serve or `ssh pi@.raspberrypi.local` for a terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not enough to set the hostname (as stated by Ghanima), you'll need to do a fix or a workaround on your router. Depending on the router firmware this may be slightly different. Most of the times you can add static ip's and names to the DHCPd settings. Or use static IP's in general (add to /etc/hosts). Or edit the hosts config on each computer that you want the access from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free hostname, like myserver.ddns.net, you could use noip.com. This would allow you to set the name and link it to the IP address (192.168.1.3). This could be changed to allow access from outside the network too.

Comment: Hello and welcome. That really does not answer the question where the Pi is on a local network and is not reachable from the internet.

Comment: @Ghanima This should work like a DNS record. I believe I did this once, but I don't remember.